# Minimum connection times through Beijing airport (PEK)?

Tags: short-connections, pek

I am planning a trip from Washington DC to Bangkok that could have a short layover in Beijing.  Both flights would be on Air China.  Will I have problems making my connecting flight due to customs or baggage issues if my layover is only 1 hr 20 min?

Comment: Are both flight legs on the same ticket?

Comment: Not knowing if both flights are on the same ticket, I did not want to post an answer. Here's a link that gives you the minimum connection times: https://www.travelchinaguide.com/cityguides/beijing/capital-airport-transfer.htm

Comment: I'm not positive about PEK but in most international airports outside the US you don't clear customs if you're just transiting. You follow the signs for connecting flights and you just have to clear security again

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beijing_Capital_International_Airport#Airlines_and_destinations) both those flights will arrive in terminal 3.  According to [Air China](http://www.airchina.com.cn/www/en/html/index/travel_information/airport_information/transfer_guides/index.shtml?smartID=50000000000), the minimum connection for international to international within terminal 3 is 60 minutes.

Anecdotally, I found controls at Beijing Cap to be surprisingly unintrusive and to not take very long(but I was arriving in the PRC).